# turtle.TurtleGraphicsError not registering?

Tags: python, error-handling, turtle-graphics, try-except

I have this code running:

```
import random
import turtle 

turtle.speed(0)
def jump(x,y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()
#end def

def random_walk(n_steps):
    turtle.goto(0,0)
    for i in range(n_steps):
        leftright = random.randint(0,10)
        if leftright<5:
            turtle.left(random.randint(0,359))
            turtle.forward(random.randint(8,12))       
        elif 5<leftright:
            turtle.right(random.randint(0,359))
            turtle.forward(random.randint(8,12))
    #end for
#end def
step = int(input("How far would you like your turtle to move?"))

while True:
    try:
        color = input("And what color would you like your turtle to be?")
        break
    except turtle.TurtleGraphicsError:
        print('Oops! i dont recognize taht color, try another!')


turtle.pencolor(color)
random_walk(step)
```

my plan was to have the code stop an error from occurring when an invalid color string was implemented however the shell still returns this error:

```
And what color would you like your turtle to be?redf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sgomena/Desktop/122/project 5/project5d.py", line 35, in <module>
    turtle.pencolor(color)
  File "<string>", line 1, in pencolor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 2252, in pencolor
    color = self._colorstr(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 2696, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 1158, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: redf
>>>
```

I have looked into it and it seems as though I should be getting a different error if the code was running properly.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s very simple! You need to insert the line where you set the pen color of your turtle (`turtle.pencolor(color)`) in your `try/except` block.

Otherwise, the exception `turtle.TurtleGraphicsError` occurs when you pass a invalid `color` to the `turtle.pencolor()` method, but there is **no** `try/except` block which handles this.

```
step =  int(turtle.numinput("Choose a distanc", "How far would you like your turtle to move?", minval=0, maxval=10))
while True:
    try:
        print(turtle.pencolor())
        color = turtle.textinput("Choose a color", "What color would you like your turtle to be?")
        turtle.pencolor(color)   # Must be inside the try/except block    
        break
    except turtle.TurtleGraphicsError:
        print('Oops! i dont recognize taht color, try another!')
```

I also recommend to use turtles input methods (`textinput()` and `numinput()`) to pop up a dialog window for the input of a string or a floating-point number (see the code above). For more information visit the [documentation site](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput).